# React Native with Expo: Unwanted android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Manifest

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-manifest

I'm developing a React Native application using Expo, and I've encountered an issue where the android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is being added to my AndroidManifest.xml, even though I haven't explicitly requested it.

I've tried to narrow down the potential libraries that might be adding this permission by disabling some of the ones I suspected, but even after building the application again, the permission persists in the manifest.

- Is there a systematic way to identify which library or part of my
  codebase is introducing this permission?
- Once identified, how can I prevent this permission from being added
  to the manifest during the build process, especially when using Expo?

For additional context, here's a list of the main libraries and their versions I'm currently using in my project:

```
    {
  "name": "my app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@amplitude/analytics-react-native": "^1.3.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-mail-composer": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-router": "2.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-appsflyer": "^6.12.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-ui-lib": "^7.5.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-native-webview": "13.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "metro": "^0.73.7",
    "metro-resolver": "^0.73.7"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "metro": "^0.73.7",
    "metro-resolver": "^0.73.7"
  },
  "private": true
}
```